# How to prove that $a^{|G|}=e$ if a $\in G $

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

How to prove that;

> $a^{|G|}=e$ if a $\in G $

if $G$ is a finite group and $e$ is its identity.

I think this could be done through pigeonhole principle but  I don't want to use the  Lagrange theorem.

How should I start?

Comment: This is essetnially just re-proving Lagrange in one line, but: the orbits under the action of $\langle a\rangle$ on $G$ by left multiplication are all of the same length, so ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Can you elaborate your comment??

Answer (score 1):

I only know a proof without Lagrange (or Lagrange in disguise) for an abelian group. Suppose that $G=\{ a_1,\ldots ,a_n\}$, and set $g:=a_1a_2\cdots a_n$. Then for every $x\in G$ the map $a_i\mapsto xa_i$ is a permutation of $G$, so that
$$
g=(xa_1)(xa_2)\cdots (xa_n)=x^na_1a_2\cdots a_n=x^ng.
$$
This implies $x^{\mid G\mid}=x^n=e$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d=ord(a)$. Then $a^d=e$ and $H=\{ e,a,a^2,...,a^{d-1} \}$ is a subgroup of $G$. By Lagrange, we have: $|G| \vdots |H|$, so $|G| \vdots d$; then, there is an $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $kd=|G|$. From this and $a^d=e$ we get that $a^{dk}=e^k$ or $a^{|G|}=e$.

Comment: I don't want to use the Lagrange .